# Appending a List with Some Values of Another List

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list of lists `mainList`. I wish to append this list with a `subList` , but only the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 7th items.

```
for subList in file:
    mainList.append(subList[#items 2,3,4,5,7])
```

Is there a way to do this besides

```
for subList in file:
    temp = []
    for item in subList[1:]:
        if #item not the 6th item:
            temp.append(item)
    mainList.append(temp)
```

Can I do this without the `temp` list and the nested for loop appending this list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this, simple and Pythonic with a list comprehension:

```
indices = 2,3,4,5,7
mainList.append([sublist[i] for i in indices])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `operator.itemegetter` to fetch the items from `subList`, returning a tuple. You can afterwards cast to a list before appending:

```
from operator import itemgetter

f = itemgetter(2,3,4,5,7)

for subList in file:
    mainList.append(list(f(subList)))
```

You may drop the list call if your sublist could also pass as tuples.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
mainList.extend(subList[1:6])
mainList.append(subList[7])
```